# The relationship between prediction intervals and no. of predictors

Tags: regression, feature-selection, model-selection

I am doing variable selection (regression) on a data set with $n$ = 120 and $p$ = 10 ~ 100. My goal is to have good prediction intervals.

If I am going to include more variables, then the prediction intervals would decrease by looking at the formula. However, I do not feel it is correct, because if I am going to add more variables, it would have some negative effects on my model.

This is just my intuition. I am not very clear what's the exact negative effect on my prediction interval and model, say if I have $p$ = 90 on $n$ = 120. The estimation of coefficients might be inaccurate but does it have something to do with my prediction intervals? (no?) Descriptions with math would be appreciated!

Comment: The introduction of new variables can help or hurt prediction. It depends on sample size, issues of multicollinearity and the amount of residual variation.  You should always be aware when looking at formulas what the all the assumptions are.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Empirically, what would you say about $p$ given $n$ = 120?